# WooCommerce change

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the code below to change one category of a regular post after a scheduled event. It works perfectly. However, I need it to target a WooCommerce product category. My question: is there a way to adjust my current code to target the custom post type?

```
// runs when a post is published
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wcsri_schedule_post_check' );

function wcsri_schedule_post_check( $post_id ) {

// set the time when the event should be scheduled
$timestamp = strtotime( '+7 days' );

// Schedule the event
wp_schedule_single_event( $timestamp, 'wcsri_check_post', array( $post_id ) 
);    
}

// a custom hook to schedule
add_action( 'wcsri_check_post', 'wcsri_check_post_cats', 10, 1 );

// replace post categories
function wcsri_check_post_cats( $post_id ) {

//categories
$old_cat = get_the_terms($post->ID, "foo");
$new_cat = get_the_terms($post->ID, "bar");

// check for the old category
if ( has_category( $old_cat, $post_id ) ) {
    // update post with new category
    $args = array(
        'ID'            => $post_id,
        'post_category' => array( $new_cat ),
    );
    wp_update_post($args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if the post is a product with [`is_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product.html) and, if it is, remember that custom taxonomies don't use `has_category()` so you have to use [`has_term( $old_cat, 'product_cat', $post_id )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/has_term) instead.

Comment: thank you very much @Peter HvD. I figured has_category() was wrong. I implemented the changes, but no effect

Comment: Don't also forget that using 'post_category' won't work as it's a custom taxonomy, not the usual WP post category tax. Anyway, instead of using `wp_update_post()`, you'd be better off using `wp_set_object_terms()` or, even better, WooCommerce's own `set_category_ids` method. So, either: `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $new_cat, 'product_cat' );` or `$product = wc_get_product($post_id); $product->set_category_ids( $new_cat ); $product->save();`